# how to do subquery with 3 tables and using where clause in multi values?

Tags: reporting-services, subquery, where-clause, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I want to do subquery with 3 tables and using where in multi values but I always get syntax error. I have to do reporting in Report Builder 3.0

Table A: record_id, Surname, Given Name

Table C: row_id, competency_code, competency_name

Table PC: link_id, record_id, row_id, attainment_date

I would like to join the tables into 1 table. One person will have some completion of competency_code and different with other person. the completion of competency_code based on the attainment_date. I also think to use iff function for attainment_date in competency_code value as complete/yes.

The table that I would like to create is:

```
Record_Id | Surname | GivenName | Code 1   | Code 2    | Code 3    | Code 4   |  Code 5
01        |  AA     |   AA      | Complete | Complete  | Complete  |          | Complete
02        |  BB     |   BB      | Complete | Complete  |           | Complete |
03        |  CC     |   CC      |          | Complete  | Complete  |          | Complete
```

here is the query that I tried to do.

```
    select distinct a.id, a.surname, a.given_name
    from all a
    join 
    (
     select pc.attainment_date
     from personnel_competency pc  
     join
     (
      select c.code, c.name 
      from competency c)
      competency c on (c.row_no = pc.linkid)
     )
     personnel_competency pc on (pc.id = a.id)

     where c.code in ('ABC', 'BCD', 'ABE', 'DEA', 'DEF', 'POS', 'SAQ', 'LOP')
     and pc.attainment_date < now()
     order by a.record_id
```

My skill in SQL is very basic. Whether other ways to make the table like that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a SQL to get your result. If so I think this is what you are looking for ..
It would help if you posted some sample data.

You can test it at 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b5fe/1/0)

Here is the script ..

```
-- Generate schema and data 
create table tableA (id int, surname varchar(30), given_name varchar(30));
create table tablePC (link_id int, id int, attainment_date datetime);
create table tableC (row_id int, competency_code varchar(20), Competency_name varchar(30));

insert into tableA (id, surname, given_name)
values (1, 'AA', 'AAgn')
, (2, 'BB', 'BBgn')

insert into tablePC (link_id, id, attainment_date)
values (1, 1, '2014-09-11')
, (2, 1, '2014-09-10')
, (3, 2, '2014-09-11')

insert into tableC (row_id, competency_code, Competency_name)
values (1, 'ABC', 'completed\Yes')
, (1, 'BCD', 'completed')
, (1, 'ABE', 'completed')
, (2, 'ABC', 'completed')
, (2, 'BCD', 'completed')
, (3, 'ABC', 'completed')
, (3, 'ABE', 'completed')
-- ===============

select *
from tableA TA
    inner join tablePC PC
    on TA.id = PC.id
    inner join
    (
        select row_id, [ABC] as ABC, [BCD] as BCD, [ABE] as ABE
        from tableC TC
        pivot
        (
            max(Competency_name)
            for Competency_code in ([ABC], [BCD], [ABE])
        ) as TCPVT
    ) TC    
    on PC.link_id = TC.row_id
where PC.attainment_date < GETDATE()
```

Comment: yes, I need SQL statement to create the table. there's incorrect syntax near pivot.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92ab/1 I've tried it at SQLFiddle but still syntax error.

Comment: There are a few errors in the script you created (good try). Please first understand your data. The data link between PC.link_id = Tc.row_id cannot be made as nothing matches based on your data, therefore no data will ever be returned. Second please research on SQL Syntax to learn how to construct your query. Have updated [Your sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92ab/64](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92ab/64)